# How To Plot an Option Payoff Graph R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can not find anything on the web regarding the solution to create an option pay off graph with intermediate steps for a complex order. Currently I can manually do this by creating a sequence of numbers and then plotting each individual point.

The end goal is to put into a shiny app and currently this is much to slow if various people will be using the app. Are there any quicker solutions? Plus I would like to make the graph a little more interactive rather than static.

Here is the code and graph for a butterfly with a one day look ahead PnL + final PnL.

```
library(derivmkts)

spot = 100
spot.sequence = seq(50, 150, .5) #create sequence to get price at each pont
body.strike = 100
itm.strike = 80
otm.strike = 120
vol = .2
Dte1 = 10
Dte.final = .01 #can not use 0 as i get an error from bscall()
butterfly.price.Dte1 = vector()
butterfly.price.Dte.final = vector()
for(i in 1:length(spot.sequence)){
body.price = bscall(spot.sequence[i], body.strike, vol, 0, Dte1/252, 0)*-2
itm.price = bscall(spot.sequence[i],itm.strike, vol,0, Dte1/252, 0)
otm.price = bscall(spot.sequence[i], otm.strike, vol, 0, Dte1/252, 0)
butterfly.price.Dte1[i] = body.price + itm.price + otm.price
}
for(i in 1:length(spot.sequence)){
      body.price = bscall(spot.sequence[i], body.strike, vol, 0, Dte.final/252, 0)*-2
      itm.price = bscall(spot.sequence[i],itm.strike, vol,0, Dte.final/252, 0)
      otm.price = bscall(spot.sequence[i], otm.strike, vol, 0, Dte.final/252, 0)
      butterfly.price.Dte.final[i] = body.price + itm.price + otm.price
}

plot(butterfly.price.Dte.final)
lines(butterfly.price.Dte1, col = "red")
```

LOL dont laugh guys!!
[image]

I would like the graph to look more like this. Obviously I don't expect any of you to do this for me, but if you could equip me with the right tools and functions I might not have heard of, I would be forever thankful.
[image]

Comment: It seems like you already have the right data, you only need to tweak the plot. You can try and look at [plotly](https://plot.ly/r/line-charts/) or [ggplot](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/)

Comment: This morning it was tagged as "Highcharts". It is not now. Did you consider using Highcharter with Highcharts.js library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this what you're asking, but a few comments: The pricing functions in `derivmkts` are all vectorized, so you don't need a loop. And you can create a `butterfly` function and use that. I don't know about speed relative to alternatives. I use the `greeks` function in the following so that inputs are returned:

```
library(derivmkts)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
butterfly <- function(s,  k1,  k2,  k3,  v,  r,  tt,  d) {
    bscall(s, k1,  v,  r,  tt,  d) -
        2*bscall(s,  k2,  v,  r,  tt,  d) +
        bscall(s,  k3,  v,  r,  tt,  d)
}
s0 <- 100
s <- seq(50,  150,  by = 0.5)
itmk <- 80; atmk <- 100; otmk <- 120
v <- 0.2
d <- 0
r <- 0
tt <- c(0.0001, .04, .5, 1)
ttexp <- 0.0001
x <- expand.grid(s = s, tt = tt)
sl <- unlist(x$s)
ttl <- unlist(x$tt)
bf <- greeks(butterfly(sl, itmk, atmk, otmk, v, r, ttl, d ), complete = TRUE)
group_by(bf, tt) %>%
    mutate(profit = butterfly(s, itmk, atmk, otmk, v, r, tt, d))  %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = s,  y = profit, color = as.factor(tt), group = tt)) +
    geom_line() + labs(color = 'Expiration')
```

[image: Butterfly spread]